# Handling SelectionChanged and MouseDown

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm

I have a WPF application using MVVM, the application contains 2 `ListBoxes`. Since I am using MVVM I am using EventTriggers in my XAML as seen below:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" 
                 Grid.Row="0"
             ItemsSource="{Binding EventLogs, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLocalLog, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             SelectionMode="Single">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadEventLogEntriesCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListBox1, Path=SelectedItem}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadEventLogEntriesCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListBox1, Path=SelectedItem}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </ListBox>
```

Code in my ViewModel:

```
this.LoadEventLogEntriesCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.LoadLog);

private void LoadLog()
{
        this.worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        this.worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(this.UpdateProgress);
        this.worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.RunWorkerCompleted);
        this.worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        this.worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        this.worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(this.ReadLog);

        // read entries
        if (worker.IsBusy != true)
        {
            worker.RunWorkerAsync(this);
        }
}
```

When I click a Row in the `ListBox`, I trigger the Event `SelectionChanged` and therefore call my `LoadLog()` Method in my ViewModel that creates a `BackgroundWorker` to do some stuff. However, I understand that this also calls my `MouseDown` event and therefore this method is being called twice since I have the EventTriggers binded to the same Command in my ViewModel.

What I want is *after* I have already clicked a row in the ListBox I want to click the same row *again* and trigger and event to run my command. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to handle the `MouseUp` event (only):

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp">
    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadEventLogEntriesCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListBox1, Path=SelectedItem}" />
</i:EventTrigger>
```

Comment: would this be in addition to SelectionChanged or just handle this event only?

Comment: Only the MouseUp event.